# Basic Coding Standard for HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, psr-1

I was wondering if their is a Basic Coding Standard for HTML and CSS like PSR-01.

I tried googling and searching but didn't find any.

Comment: There are a lot. Check out http://codeguide.co/ and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at these:

- [Code Guide](http://codeguide.co)
- [GitHub StyleGuide](https://github.com/styleguide)
- [Google StyleGuide](https://github.com/google/styleguide)
- [CSS Tricks StyleGuide](https://css-tricks.com/css-style-guides/)
- [SMACSS](https://smacss.com/)
- [BEM](https://en.bem.info/method/)

Comment: Would you mind comparing among each other and point out which is better for modern apps?

Comment: @PennyLiu Just follow the MDN guidelines. That's now doing way better. Also, the above resources are great as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at something like [W3C](http://www.w3.org/) standards.

They have code checkers on the site that you can run CSS and HTML through.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check SMACSS - https://smacss.com/ it's not official or something but it's very useful architecture for building your websites. There is also methodology called BEM - https://en.bem.info/method/